# Linking to dynamically available functions at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, compile-time

Suppose I have the following core class:

```
class Core {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void accept(T object);
}
```

I now want to be able to write methods like this:

```
void handle(int par);
```

and register them **somewhere** during **linking/compiling** stage and call the correct method registered for some typename in the `Core.accept(T)` method. For example calling
`Core.accept(5)` would hand `5` over to the `handle(int)` function after it is somehow registered. Something like this (not compilable example):

```
template<typename T>
void Core::accept(T par) {
    // constexpr std::map<std::type_info, Function> type_func_mapping;
    auto it = type_func_mapping.get(typeid(T)); // Should be constexpr
    static_assert (it != type_func_mapping.end(), "No handler found for typename " + typeid(T).name())
    auto function = *it; // Also constexpr
    function(par);
}
```

Are there any problems with this approach/does exist a better one?

Note: I want to be able to extract the sources of class Core in a way that I can store them in a read-only header/source file and don't even have to touch them again.

Comment: Why can't you define a header file with lots of `void handle(int par); void handle(double par); void handle(foo_class par);` overloads? I'm afraid I don't quite understand what your requirements and goals are.

Comment: as dyp notes above, there's no reason to have this weird factory that maps from type to function. You can just do function overloading based on call type, it will do everything you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use pointer to functions to store the registered function.

```
static void (*reg_func)(args);
static void register(void (*func)(args)){
reg_func = func;
}

//registration part
register(handle);

//function call inside accept,use can use some sanity checks also
reg_func(5 or whatever)
```

With this you don't have to touch your core class or even the file containing the core class. You can define the handle function in some other file but take care of visibility mode of handle function. Your handle function will register itself and then accept can call the registered function.

Comment: Is this compile-time static? I doubt. Does this work for registering multiple functions at once (so different template typenames call different functions)? I can't see that. Feel free to surprise me.

Comment: If you want it to be compile-time static, there is no way around Core's code "effectively" changing. What I mean by this is that you can keep Core.h and Core.cpp identical, but Core.h will have to include some file, indirect.h, which will have to be modified as you add new types of handle functions. Ultimately, what I'm really trying to say: as you add new handles, you will need to recompile Core.o if you want things to be compile-time static... this is totally unavoidable.